# Upon button click, generate an array of strings, display it on the page, with a button that would generate another random array

Tags: javascript, html, dom, client-side

New to DOM so I'm not totally sure how to add to an HTML file correctly and listen for events. Here is my JS:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
document.querySelector("div#intro button").addEventListener("click", function () {

    const forest = [];

    const possible = ["tree", "leaf", "bush"];
    for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            let text = '';
            for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
            }
            forest.push(text);
        }
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < forest.length; i++) {
        let row = document.createElement("div");
        row.appendChild(document.createTextNode(forest[i]);
        document.body.getElementById("sim").appendChild(row);
    }

    let button = document.createElement("button");
    button.appendChild(document.createTextNode("generate"));
    document.body.getElementById("sim").appendChild(row);
});
});
```

Am I adding correctly to my DOM? And how do I get the generated array to display correctly, as well as continually generate arrays once the button is pressed?

Comment: You are generating it correctly, you might wanna create common function from where you can generate the array and append it.

Comment: Any idea why the array and button is not displaying?

Comment: Creating a snippet would help to identify the problem

Comment: I'm confused as to how when I run code in the SO snippet, it's giving me errors that my Terminal isn't giving me?